# How to pad a string with spaces

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to create a function which converts the following string:

```
1110100010000000101000011000011110000000000000000000000000111101110000110101100111
```

to:

```
1110100010000000 1010 0001 1000 0111 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011 1101 1100 0011 0101 1001 11
```

(groups of four 1's/0's)

Some function like the following:

```
convert(char *src_buffer,char *dst_buffer,int offset){

}
```

where "offset" is 16 in the above case.

Here's the code I've tried sofar:

```
char *tmp=(char*)malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
strncpy(tmp,buffer,i);
tmp[i+1]=' ';
for(int j=0;j<sizeof(buffer);j++){
    strcpy(tmp+sizeof(tmp),buffer+(4*j));
    tmp[(5*j)+1]=' ';
}
```

But it just won't work...

Please help! I'm hoping there's a C guru out there who can help me.

Here's some updated code I've been working on:

```
char *tmp=(char*)malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
strncpy(tmp,buffer,offset);
tmp[offset+1]=' ';
int k=offset+1;
for(int j=i;j<strlen(buffer);j+=4){
    tmp[k]=buffer[j];
    tmp[k+1]=buffer[j+1];
    tmp[k+2]=buffer[j+2];
    tmp[k+3]=buffer[j+3];
    tmp[k+5]=' ';
    k+=5;
}
```

Comment: Where, EXACTLY, do you want the spaces? I see groups of 4 and 3, not to mention the big string at the start.

Comment: Offset is 16. The spaces should separate groups of four. The fact that the last chunk is of length three is as a result of the offset specification.

Comment: Please, [don't cast the return value of `malloc()`, in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169). Also, don't scale by `sizeof (char)`, it's just an annoying way of writing `1`. Also, what is `i`?

Comment: What are the `i` and `offset`? There seems no correlation to the function definition you gave and the function declaration you gave.

Comment: The big string at the start is the result of the offset, it appears OP wants a space immediately after the offset, then every fifth space (4 chars then space). The string in the example I'm sure contains typos.

Comment: The groups of 3 at the end are curious but the first block is explained by him mentioning the offset of 16.

Comment: If `buffer` is a pointer, `sizeof(buffer)` returns the _size of the pointer_, not what it points to.

Comment: @joe: Its really ambiguous until OP guides us in a proper way!

Comment: @eznme The block of 3 is a result of the offset being defined 16. If offset=17, there would be a block of 2 at the end.

Comment: There are several blocks of three at the end though - why ?

Comment: The algorithm you are using is bit unclear. Try to explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @PaulR Yes, you're right. Fixed the OP now. I was clicking my keyboard too fast. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: Joachim got it. I'm outta here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
int len = strlen(src);
char *dst= malloc(len * sizeof *dst * 2);
/* copy the first (offset) bytes */
strncpy(dst, src, offset); 

for(i=j=offset; j<len; i++, j++){
    /* add a whitespace and once every 5 characters */
    if ((i-offset)%5 == 0) { 
       dst[i++] = ' ';
    }
    dst[i] = src[j];
}
/* null-terminate string */
dst[i]=0;
```

As a side note, If every character is followed by a space (which is not the case) then you would need maximum twice as much as the original string, so no need to allocate 1000 bytes.

Comment: Side-side note. No need to `*sizeof(char)` since that will always be `1`

Comment: @Mike actually no that's implementation defined and not guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: This: `6.5.3.4 paragraph 4: "When sizeof is applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned char, or signed char, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1."`  Is incorrect?

Comment: @mux as Mike pointed out it is quite the contrary, that is the only guarantee made by the standard for `sizeof`.

Comment: @Mike you're right, I was confused for a minute, I removed it.

Comment: @Eamorr I updated the code because it didn't handle the first whitespace correctly with offsets not divisible by 4.

Answer (score 3):

Copy the first `offset` characters to the temporary buffer. Then loop over each character in the remaining original buffer, one by one, copying them into the temporary buffer. Every fourth loop add a space to the temporary buffer.